# How can I make auto-complete work with ELPY?

Tags: python, emacs, elpy

I am currently trying to install the ELPY package for Emacs, which is a Python development mode.

I am following the instructions on the Github page, but am having issues.

When I evaluate the following expressions

```
(package-initialize)
(elpy-enable)
```

I see the following in the minibuffer:

[image]

After that, auto-complete does not work in the mode, although I do see a "Python" item in the top Emacs menu when I am in an `*.py` file. This may be some other that does that.

Could someone tell me how to make auto-complete work with ELPY?

It appears that the mode is working, except for auto-complete. I expected something like this to happen, but it does not.

https://files.realpython.com/media/emacs-elpy-basic.5b8849610482.png

Comment: Well, I am not seeing any auto-complete. For example, I expected something like this https://files.realpython.com/media/emacs-elpy-basic.5b8849610482.png
The commands seem to be available via `M-x` and the ones I check work. I suppose that the thing works, except for auto-complete.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect what you really want to know, according to your comment. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I find elpy-config helpful. Try M-x elpy-config

Then install any python packages that it says are missing. Missing jedi can cause company to not work. You can install jedi from the window that elpy-config brings up.